# Why Chart ApplyDataLabels doesn't work at Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts, label, series

I'm building some charts at Access 2010 and trying to automate them.
But I couldn't to apply data labels via vba.

When I try to use ApplyDataLabels, I got the error 438:

```
Dim mychart As Object
Dim myseries As Object
Dim ax As Object
Dim pt As Object

Set mychart = frm.ChartSpace.Charts(0)

For Each myseries In mychart.SeriesCollection
    myseries.ApplyDataLabels '438 - Object doesn't support this property or method
Next
```

What do I need to do to make datalabel usable?

Thanks in advance!

Fábio.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
Dim dl as Object
For Each myseries In mychart.SeriesCollection
        Set dl = myseries.DataLabelsCollection.Add
        dl.NumberFormat = "0.00"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure shows/hides the values based on the data passed with the bShow parameter. The graph object is set from a form object (oFrmGrafico) that has a control of type Graph called Grafico (`oFrmGrafico!Grafico.Object`).

`util_Log_MsgBoxErr` is an internal procedure. Yo can change it by `MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation`

`mbExisteGrafico` is a Boolean variable of global scope that collects whether or not a graph exists.

```
Public Sub MostrarValores(ByVal bMostrar As Boolean)
On Error GoTo MostrarValores_Err

    Dim objGraph As Object  'Chart
    Dim srs As Object       'Series
    Dim pt As Object        'Point
    
    If mbExisteGrafico Then
        Set objGraph = oFrmGrafico!Grafico.Object
        With objGraph
            .ApplyDataLabels
            For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
                For Each pt In srs.Points
                    pt.DataLabel.ShowValue = bMostrar
                Next
            Next
        End With
    End If

MostrarValores_Sal:
On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = Nothing
    Set srs = Nothing
    Set objGraph = Nothing
    Exit Sub
MostrarValores_Err:
    util_Log_MsgBoxErr Err.Number, Err.Description, "Class|Sub: cGraficos", "MostrarValores"
    Resume MostrarValores_Sal
End Sub
```